# Same string content but different lengths

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, selenium, string-comparison

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. I'm writing a Unit test that verifies that the MD5 that a site displays matches the actual MD5 of the file. I do this by simply grabbing what the page displays and then calculating my own MD5 of the file. I get the text on the page by using Selenium WebDriver.

As expected, the strings show up as the same...*or it appears to be*

When I try to test the two strings using `Assert.AreEqual` or `Assert.IsTrue`, it fails no matter how I try to compare them

I've tried the following ways:

```
Assert.AreEqual(md5, md5Text); //Fails
Assert.IsTrue(md5 == md5Text); //Fails
Assert.IsTrue(String.Equals(md5, md5Text)); //Fails
Assert.IsTrue(md5.Normalize() == md5Text.Normalize()); //Fails
Assert.AreEqul(md5.Normalize(), md5Text.Normalize()); //Fails
```

At first, I thought the strings were actual different, but looking at them in the debugger shows that both strings are exactly the same
[image]

So I tried looking at their lengths, that's when I saw why

[image]

The strings are different lengths..so I tried to substring the `md5` variable to match the size of the `md5Text` variable. My thinking here was maybe `md5` had a bunch of 0 width characters. However doing this got rid of the last half of `md5`

***SOO***, this must mean their in different encodings correct? But wouldn't `Normalize()` fix that?

This is how the variable `md5` is created

```
string md5;
using (var stream = file.Open()) //file is a custom class with an Open() method that returns a Stream
{
    using (var generator = MD5.Create())
    {
        md5 = BitConverter.ToString(generator.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "‌​").ToLower().Trim();
    }
}
```

and this is how the `md5Text` variable is created

```
//I'm using Selenium WebDrvier to grab the text from the page
var md5Element = row.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[@data-bind='text: MD5Hash']")).Where(e => e.Visible()).First();
var md5Text = md5Element.Text;
```

How can I make this test pass? as it should be passing (since *they are* the same)

**UPDATE:**

The comments suggested I turn the strings into a char[] and iterate over it. Here are the results of that (http://pastebin.com/DX335wU8) and the code I added to do it

```
        char[] md5Characters = md5.ToCharArray();
        char[] md5TextCharacters = md5Text.ToCharArray();

        //Use md5 length since it's bigger
        for (int i = 0; i < md5Characters.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("md5: " + md5Characters[i]);

            if (i >= md5TextCharacters.Length)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" | Exhausted md5Text characters..");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" | md5Text: " + md5TextCharacters[i]);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
        }
```

One thing I found interesting is that the md5 char array has a bunch of random characters inside of it every 2 letters

[image]

Comment: Examine `var contents = md5.ToCharArray()` in the debugger and see where/what the extra bytes are.

Comment: What happens if you enumerate both strings char by char and compare them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Replace("-", "‌​")`

Your `""` is not empty, there is actually a `"‌​` then unicode *zero width non-joiner*  + *zero width space* then `"` so you are not replacing `"-"` with an empty string rather you are inserting additional characters.

Delete and retype `""` or use `String.Empty`.

Comment: **YES**, this was it. When trying to delete the `""` in the IDE I had to hit backspace 4 times instead of 2. I've replaced it with `String.Empty` and the test now passes.